# TIA: Is OP-AMP necessary when low speed and high current gain?

Tags: transimpedance-amplifier

I've read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/654619/why-would-a-photodiode-with-an-op-amp-be-very-linear).

Regarding this picture:

[image]

If there conditions are satisfy:

- Gain resistor is very high e.g. 10Meg rather than 10k
- Low speed close to DC
- Connect this circuit output to ADC input, and input impedance of ADC is about 300 ohm

  - 10Meg || 280 does not seems to have loading effect

then shouldn’t I need OP-AMP(TIA)?

Comment: What ADC? What purpose does the 10Meg serve if it's just going to be shunted by something massively lower than it anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit has a rather large "input impedance" equal to R, while a TIA has essentially 0 input impedance. As a result, the voltage over the diode will be not constant and this will deteriorate linearity.

Moreover, the output impedance is also R, so connecting it to a low impedance ADC is not gonna work at all.

Better, but still without a TIA, would be to strap a basic current mirror between the diode and the I-to-V- conversion resistor.